# Return fn function not returning value

Tags: javascript

Return fn statement returns undefined

from my furnace controller:

```
dbController.getFurnaceSettings(furnaceSettings.state, function (tempFurnaceSettings){
console.log("* * * in furnace controller just back from getting settings");
console.log(tempFurnaceSettings.state);
    ...
})

// over in the db controller:
// called by the furnace controller
exports.getFurnaceSettings = function (HomeState, fn){
   console.log("Current state - " + HomeState);

   var sqltest = "SELECT * FROM furnaceSettings WHERE state IN ('" + HomeState + "')";
       connection.query (sqltest, function (err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log(result);
         return ( fn (result) )
     });
};
```

the console log in the db controller shows the correct data, so I know my sql is good,
but over in the furnace controller I'm getting undefined.
This used to work, but I recently converted from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3) not sure if that's relevant...

lots of searches didn't help

Comment: So what exactly is the logging output of this?